# Playback stuttering with video in HEVC / H.265 with Windows 10/11

Tags: windows-10, video, h.265

I have a problem that I was hoping to solve by formatting the PC.

I have always been able to play smoothly on each player 2K 59.94fps video files with H.265 codec (HEVC) filmed with a GoPro 8 with a bitrate of 100 Mb\s.

I generally use MPV player x64 or VLC x64 or Media Player Classic Home Cinema x64 (MPC-HC > K-lite codec).

Suddenly, video playback was smooth ONLY with native Windows 10 Pro x64 player with (official HEVC codec installed from Windows Store). With all the other players the videos were suddenly terribly jerky. Only the audio is regular. I thought formatting would fix it.

So I installed (clean installation) Windows 10 Pro but the problem remained. I tried installing Windows 11 Pro from scratch but... the problem remains. I also tried installing Windows without installing the K-lite codec suite to rule out conflicts and without installing anything else: including AV etc. No way! You have ideas?.

This thing is driving me crazy. When editing video with effects applied, for convenience I use proxies (in Premiere or Davinci Resolve) but from Windows the original video file was perfect it's incredibly smooth. I don't understand what could be causing this problem.

> **PC configuration:**
>
> - CPU: Intel i7-2600K
> - MB: MSI P67A-GD65 (B3) STORAGE: OCZ Vertex 3
> - SATAIII 120gb + WD Caviar Black 2TB
> - RAM: G.Skill Ripjaws-X-F3-12800CL9Q 16GB XL
> - GPU: ATI FirePro W5100
> - OS: Windows 11 - Pro 22H2 - Build: 22621.1485 - Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22639.1000.0 (with all latest updates installed)